# "his best-seller book" or "his best-selling book"

Tags: word-choice

> The author got a lot of money from his **best-seller**
>
> or
>
> The author got a lot of money from his **best-selling book**
>
> or
>
> The author got a lot of money from his **best-seller book**

Which one is correct?

Comment: They're syntactically different, but all are commonly used and mean the same (i.e. - there isn't a concept of "correct/incorrect" here).

Answer (score 1):

Your question centers around

> best-seller  *(noun)*
>   best-selling  *(adjective)*

So to describe an author's book

> He has a best-seller.
>   He has a best-selling book.

are both correct.

"Best-seller book" would not be correct, however

> His book which is a best-seller.

is correct.

Comment: That's my initial hunch, too, but I see that "best seller" is sometimes used as an adjective (often hyphenated). Examples: _His research was continued by the International Motor Vehicle Program at MIT, which later produced the international [best-seller book](http://www.industryleadersmagazine.com/why-did-google-pick-john-krafcik-as-the-new-ceo-for-its-self-driving-car-project/) called “The Machine That Changed the World” in 1990;_

Comment: _Best selling author Gary Chapman introduced the concept of love languages in his [New York Times Best Seller book](http://pctechmag.com/2016/02/10-most-popular-love-emojis-on-twitter/) “The Five Love Languages..."; Piketty, the author of the [best-seller book](http://www.dnaindia.com/money/report-india-yet-to-provide-one-access-to-income-tax-statistics-economist-2206047) 'Capital in the Twenty-First Century', is a faculty at the Paris School of Economics._ Perhaps it's an accepted informalism?

Comment: I agree with the thrust of this answer that *best-selling book* is the better term. @J.R. If something is a *New York Times Best Seller*, the whole five word string is the adjective in use to modify *book*, although why *book* is specified is beyond me; perhaps to distinguish it from a "best seller" audio. If a book appears on a "Best Seller List*, I guess the generic  "best seller book" is okay, but I don't like it much. Otherwise, "best-selling book* is what I'd expect to describe a book that sold or is selling well without reference to it being named a "best seller" by a publication.